# E-mail and Real Name user profile field labels are red

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, profile-page, design

Minor bug, I know. I'm not sure if this is new or not; I haven't noticed it before, but that doesn't mean it hasn't been like this all along...

[image]
[image]

Those two labels have the `moderator-visible` CSS class applied, while the other labels do not. This is reproducible on multiple sites (I checked Meta, SO, SF, and Gaming -- so probably network-wide) where they all display with the *same* colour.

Edit, as a response to Rebecca's answer, which she deleted: Since I never noticed this until now, perhaps that feature is too subtle -- maybe a tooltip saying "this field is only visible to you and moderators" would make it more discoverable.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was a duplicate of [Bobby's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79110/e-mail-and-real-name-user-profile-field-labels-are-red/79111#79111).  I've asked about your follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've removed this indicator on the fields, as they were used inconsistently and it was ultimately more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is intentional. Those are 'private' fields, which only the moderators will see.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @Rebecca - In that case shouldn't the "visited", "openid" and "alt openid" labels be red too?

Comment: @chrisf actually the grey already signifies that, it's just become a little less clear as we added hotness to the date of account creation

Comment: @Jeff - ah you mean the grey of the content - I was confused as I couldn't see any grey labels ;)

Comment: @Jeff - but my Real Name isn't grey either.

Comment: @Jeff: Then why is the "member for" text gray also? I can see that information on other users' profiles.

Comment: @kon see my answer directly above where you commented please.

Comment: @Jeff: Where you said "The grey already signifies that"? But what is that? Am I not seeing a deleted comment?

Comment: @kon search for the words "removed this indicator" on this page

Comment: @Jeff: I really didn't see it, and asked around in the chat - noone knew. So I made a [shiny new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84015/why-are-some-profile-fields-contents-grey-and-others-black) :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is to indicate that the field are "private" and only visible to you and moderators  shouldn't the "visited", "openid" and "alt openid" labels be red too?