# Why are some profile fields (contents) grey, and others black?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

This started as a comment on [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79110/e-mail-and-real-name-user-profile-field-labels-are-red), but I don't understand what Jeff told me, so I'm posting this as a question. Sorry if I'm just not seeing it :)

[The question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79110/e-mail-and-real-name-user-profile-field-labels-are-red) asked why some profile field labels are red. [Bobby answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79110/e-mail-and-real-name-user-profile-field-labels-are-red/79111#79111) they are "private fields", which only mods see.
[Jeff then answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79110/e-mail-and-real-name-user-profile-field-labels-are-red/83365#83365) they removed this indicated, as they were used inconsistently and it was ultimately more confusing than useful.

I'm asking why some profile field contents is grey. I asked in a comment on Bobby's answer, Jeff told me he already answered - but I really can't find it. I see what red labels did, I see they are removed, but nothing about grey text. And grey text was not removed: I still see it.

So, what is the meaning of the grey content on certain profile fields?

[image]

Comment: I think site and mail are red because they are links, and links are red. But indeed, you can see my `member for` field info, even though it's grey, so grey could not mean `private info`.

Comment: If this is really a feature request please specify what exactly is your request, otherwise retag the question as "Support" or "Discussion". For the record, I wonder about those colors as well.. :)

Comment: It's actually a `documentation-request`, but I can't create that tag yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, by observation I'd say:

- Black: info you entered
- Grey: calculated or generated values
- Red: urls

Comment: Urls you mean links? The "Seen" information is neither URL nor link so it kind of breaking this - apart of that your observation looks correct. :)

Comment: I didn't enter my age, I entered my date of birth. Age was calculated so it should be grey ;)

Comment: OK, I'll leave it there. team@ can now defend their baby. My explanation was coherent, reality should now conform :)

Comment: *The Guide is definitive. Reality is frequently inaccurate.* - [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Chapter_6_2)

Comment: ...also "visited" is black nowadays, should be grey (again) I think!