# Wrong migration text for questions from meta.tex.sx

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

At [Make clear which profile data is visible to whom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97964/162565) it says:

[image: migrated from meta.tex.stackexchange.com ... This question came from our site for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems.]

The lower sentence is wrong, since we're talking about a *meta* site. The same problem appears for [questions migrated from meta.tex.sx to tex.sx (main)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30326/4012):

[image: migrated from meta.tex.stackexchange.com ... This question came from our site for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems.]

... and has been discussed on meta.tex.sx: [Migration from meta to main site gives wrong 'migration text'](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1829/4012)

Comment: This was also reported on [Gaming's meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3357/4076).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When questions are migrated from a meta site the migration text will now read:

> This question came from our discussion, support, and feature requests
>   site for *audience*.

This will be in after the next deploy.