# Add the ability to see your public profile on Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I think it would be a very useful feature to see my profile as others see it on Stack Exchange. Perhaps in the form of a "Public profile" button on the user's profile that would allow me to see my profile as others see it.

I've seen some questions related to this for the Stack Overflow Careers site, but I don't use that one... yet. LinkedIn has a button that shows your public profile, but I don't see anything like that here.

One of several motivations would be, for example: I have my email address on there, can others see it? Sure I could just remove it if I didn't want others to see it.

Also, when I look at other users, I see their `% accept rate` but I don't see that for myself.

Comment: No such option is built into the system yet, I would support a request to add such option instead of having to use another browser session or private mode etc which I consider not so elegant hack.

Comment: Ok, how do I create such a request? Would it be enough to add/change this question's tag to feature-request?

Comment: Yes indeed, just edit your question explaining you want such thing possible from within the site, for example "view my public profile" link somewhere and change the *support* tag to *feature-request*, or start brand new question for this.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I edited the original question to make it a *feature-request* Thanks!

Comment: Yes please, if only as a workaround for [Make clear which profile data is visible to whom](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom).

Comment: @random, why did you change the tag from feature-request to support?

Comment: @Arjan, its Brady, not Brandy :) I originally asked the question as a support request, and as can be seen in previous comments, I was requested to make a `feature-request`, which I did. Now @random changed it to support again, so obviously Im a bit confused. I see your point about the title, but it was due to the history of the question. I'll edit the post now, thanks.

Comment: Despite the retag it was written as support

Answer (score 16):

> How do I see my profile as others see it on Stack Overflow?

Simply open up a browser in private browsing mode (firefox) or incognito mode (chome) and navigate to your profile (without logging in of course).

[image: screenshot]

> I have my email address on there, can others see it?

No - only you can see it and moderators/dev's can see it for the purpose of contacting you should there be some problems with your account.

> <s>Is that (accept rate) something only other people see?</s>

**Short answer** - You accept rate will only appear once you have four questions posted and it'll also only appear on **your** questions.
**Long answer** - See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16729/152859) for an indepth explanation ([thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131208/how-do-i-see-my-public-profile-on-stack-overflow#comment361439_131209) to [@sha-dow-wiz-ard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-dow-wiz-ard) for the reference).

Comment: ok, thanks. Opening another browser seems like a work-around though.

Comment: That's the best way to see **anything** as a *public user*.

Comment: Uggg, I think I'll have to change that pic! :) Thanks!

Comment: As for accept rate it's more complicated than that (e.g. even if you have 20 questions but less than four with answers you won't have visible accept rate) it's explained very clearly [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16729/152859) :)

Comment: @Lix, I just un-accepted your answer as it was suggested that accepting an answer may affect them actually implementing the feature-request. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133080/184933