# Make it clearer what information is disclosed publicly from our own profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make clear which profile data is visible to whom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom)

It is hard to tell exactly what information is disclosed publicly and what privately.

Here is an image from both views:

[image]

I know they won't share my email using common sense, but the list is big and it is hard to remember all of them.

There are two options:

- Put a little mark on the ones that private
- Implement the [Add the possibility to see your public profile on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131208/add-the-possibility-to-see-your-public-profile-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe Area 51 profiles already do this. The options not displayed to the public are in red text.
Expand it throughout the network!

[image: Area51 Profile Fields]

Unless that's not really what the red text is for... then I'm *really* confused...

Comment: I think it was like that on SO main until the profile page redesign (or there about)

Comment: Yeah, that was lost somehow in the profile redesign.

Comment: @Shog9: Will they bring it back?

Comment: Well, go vote for that other feature-request...