# A user should be able to see their profile without logging out

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, login, users, logout

Given the new profile changes, I'd like to give users a preview, or ability to see their profile as someone else would.

The logout button is not easy to find and I think people should be given the option to "view my profile as another user".

This is especially more prudent since the site is adding text to the user's profile (I think it's fine, but the user needs to know it is there).

---

[Add the ability to see your public profile on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131208/add-the-ability-to-see-your-public-profile-on-stack-exchange) is asking the same thing, but it is from 2012. There was accept rate etc back then, and the profile page was very, very different.

Given recent changes to it, this could be left - [the reasons a user should be able to see it are quite different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251810/the-site-should-not-make-speculative-statements-about-its-users).

Comment: I swear I've seen this be asked before! Can't find the question though :) +1 Just use the private mode of your browser ;)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Can this be left because of recent changes to the profile page?

Comment: I guess the reason behind the request is different... but it's still asking for the same thing! . Anyways, your decision - you have a binding vote :) Or wait for more people to decide :)

Comment: Yeah I'll wait a bit. If I get more close votes i'll close it.

Comment: I don't even know where the logout button is nowadays, but right-click + "open in a private window" (Chrome/Windows) seems simple enough. In fact, if there was a button for "public view", I probably would have more trouble finding it.

Comment: @Yes It may do (as you know how to) but I bet a lot of people don't know how to. Also mobile...?

Comment: My mobile browser works in the same way: context menu -> private tab.

Comment: The putative duplicate is from 2012 and amongst other things refers to 'accept rate' which has long gone. In other words, it is about a very different version of the profile from the current one.  That makes it a less than ideal duplicate.

Comment: @Tim *"I bet a lot of people don't know how to"* Think of this like a good opportunity to encourage those people to click the main menu of their favorite web browser once to see what's in it. It's a good general skill to have.

Comment: The profile design changes, but the core of the request and the immediate answer  ("use incognito mode") remain the same. Feel free to post an answer on the duplicate to support your argument or edit the question itself to include additional detail.