# Last activity link does not look like a link

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design, last-activity

Here are the activity panels from Gaming, SO, and Sci-Fi:

[image: activity panels of three different sites]

Is it any wonder why I thought for the longest time that it wasn't possible to view `?lastactivity` from the question's page?

Please change the colour (or add some sort of underline to) of `lastactivity-link` so that one can tell it's a link without having to roll over it.

EDIT: Apparently, Internet Explorer 7 shows the link as a different colour. Since it's not a supported browser, I'm getting the feeling that the link's camouflage is intentional for some reason.

Comment: Let's also change the color of the Stack Exchange dropdown, your username, your reputation, chat, main, faq, the vote buttons, link, edit, close, flag, most dates, the tags, the question title, the linked and related questions, ...

Comment: @Arjan This seems a bit specious; your username, chat, main, and faq *are* colored as links, and the rest are obviously links from context. This happens to be a case where it looks like the site is just giving you information, but it's actually a link somewhere else

Comment: It doesn't look like a link...but it's also not really important enough to require prominent display IMO. It's fine if only power users know about it (if anyone)

Comment: Ah, @Michael, you're saying red indicates a link? [I wish.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom/128614#128614) ;-)

Comment: Just think of it as an easter egg.

Answer (score 10):

Until now I've hadn't noticed this as a feature.

I think recolouring the link would give it too much prominence in the sidebar. 
A simple underline or dotted line would be more suitable.