# Hide email address from my profile

Tags: support, profile-page, email, privacy

I don't want to show my email address in my Stack Overflow profile. I have removed my email address by editing my profile and saving it.

After some time (time is random, sometimes a day, sometimes within couple of hours) my email address is showing up again.

How can I hide my email address?

Comment: Any information you can see in your profile but not someone else's is private. This is consistent across all sites, and there is no reputation privilege that lets people see more of other users' profiles.

Comment: Well, @Popular, that is: if you're sure others entered those details to start with ;-) And related: [Make clear which profile data is visible to whom](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom).

Comment: @Arjan I realize you were kidding, but for completeness: even if someone hasn't filled a given field in, there's still a placeholder. For example, I see spaces for "website" and "age" in your profile.

Comment: Ah, @Popular, I was not really kidding about that, but you proved me wrong. You're very right about the placeholders (and, of course, I did not enter some space there); I did not realize that!

Comment: Oh, I figured that was what the smiley was for, @Arjan. And you did make me think about the possibility of people simply filling in spaces, so we both got something out of this. I upvoted the post you linked, since the interface certainly is not clear about what is/isn't private.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your email is already hidden from the public. Only you can see your email address in your profile.

If you have a Gravatar associated with it, I would keep it.

Comment: That is good to know. Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: @thinksteep For the sake of full disclosure, diamond moderators and Stack Exchange employees can see your email address too.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: That make sense. I just want hide it from other community members(SE moderators & employees it's ok)

Comment: @BilltheLizard, if I change the email address, can the diamond moderators see all previous email address too?

Comment: @user1271772 Sorry, I don't remember. It's been a few years since I've been a moderator, so they might have changed things as well.

Answer (score 16):

Your email address is only visible to you, it is not public information.

However, if you have an email address associated with an account you use to log in (such as Google, Facebook, etc.) then Stack Overflow will update your account with that email address from time to time if the email address field is empty.

Comment: That is good to know. Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: Also, if you log in via Stack Exchange, you can't delete or change the e-mail field, or it will complain about it being invalid.