# Profile picture change after editing user profile fields

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, profile-picture

I always had the auto-generated Identicon picture as my profile picture. 
Yesterday I edited some fields in my user profile and my profile picture suddenly changed to another Identicon.

I liked my old one. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, change your email address to your old address.

The Gravatar auto-generated image is based on your email address, change *that*, and the image changes with it.

If you really, really liked it but want to use your new email address, you'll have to save the image and upload that image as a fixed profile picture instead. Change your email address to the old, right-click the generated Gravatar image to save it to your disk. Change your email address back and upload the saved image to your profile.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I removed my email address.

Comment: If I put my email address in the profile, will it be publicly visible?

Comment: No, your email address is only visible to you and diamond moderators. See [Hide email address from my profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144665)

Comment: Got it back, thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1981275 the gravatar does expose your email **hash** and I've seen reports that it's not 100% secure and hackers might be able to decode it back to your email. Personally not sure how true this is, but if it concerns you upload your desired picture and you'll be 100% safe.

Comment: Questions related to what Sh Wiz Dow Ard mentioned about Gravatar, in case you want to read more: [Is Gravatar a privacy risk?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44717), [Is using Gravatar a security risk?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21117), [If your anonymity is critical to you, change your profile picture - Gravatar is a privacy risk](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191827)

Comment: I had a custom avatar set, and when I changed my email address, it set it back to being a gravatar. that shouldn't happen should it?

Comment: I don't know; I use a gravatar and never change my email address. But clicking on the 'Change profile picture' area should give you the choice to switch back.