# Email privacy - published on profile

Tags: profile-page, privacy, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make clear which profile data is visible to whom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom)

On my profile are fields 'website', 'real name' and 'email'. I deliberately left the 'real name' field blank and when I signed up, Stack Overflow promised not to publish my email. Yet there it is :(

---

Edit: Apparently profiles look different when logged in. Some fields in that list are public some are private. I think they should be marked private rather than displayed the same as the public fields.

Comment: It is not visible. Link to what you mean

Comment: Try to logout, then go to your user profile. Your email is not publicly shown.

Comment: On your profile are fields 'website', 'location' and 'age' all of which are blank - i just looked.

Comment: What made you post this on the main site? You are long time member here on Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You profile page looks different from mine.

Mine also has:

1. Email
2. Real Name
3. Visited