# Profile Gravatar get change

Tags: discussion, support, gravatar

Do not know whether someone else observe it or not but today I found my profile Gravatar changed. It is now different than earlier I have. Is it because today I have updated my profile information?

> [image: gravatar]

My previous gravatar looks like:

> [image: old one]

Comment: Are you sure you're using a Gravatar? It clearly says you uploaded a picture.

Comment: I uploaded but the revert back to gravatar

Comment: Interestingly when I view your profile I see your gravatar as the one you posted at the bottom, but on this question I see the one at the top.

Comment: Actually I just did a Shift+ Refresh and it went back to your old one in both places. Caching issue???

Comment: @JoshMein no I changed it by changing email, when you were refreshing....

Comment: Man this is so confusing...I wish there were just a checkbox option to use gravatar still, or that it were greyed out if SE hasn't detected you have a linkable gravatar account or what not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out the reason behind this behavior. Gravatar gets changed if someone changes the email address in the profile. As I recently changed my profile information which caused it. But in my opinion, it should link to the login email ID and should not be changed with profile one.

reverted to old gravatar here:

> [image: old]

and the new one is here with a different email Id:

> [image: new]

Comment: If it went off of the authentication email address, your gravatar would change every time you logged in with a different authentication type. That wouldnt be very ideal. The profile seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 7):

If you know you aren't using a picture uploaded to gravatar use the identicon. The picture changing popup actually checks if you uploaded a picture to gravatar for you current email address, and hides the option if it doesn't find one. The identicon option is safer since it uses different values to generate the gravatar hash, thus helping to disguise your email address from an attacker wanting to retrieve it from the hash, like described in [Is using Gravatar a security risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk) This is the default option used for new users. Unfortunately you've created your account before this change was made, so you still have the gravatar option enabled, but don't see it when you want to change you profile picture (no gravatar account).

Since you are posting a screenshot showing your email address you clearly aren't concerned with disguising it from potential attackers.

Comment: So does it mean that Stack Exchange officially stop using [Gravatar](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/gravatars-identicons-and-you/)?

Comment: No. The identicons still come from gravatar, but not via a hash calculated from your email address. Users can still opt in to a gravatar if they have a gravatar account with an image.

Comment: Thanks, *think* I got it. There were some posts about the security risk in Gravatar, should we direct them here now?

Comment: yes, we should, since it's related