# Why has Community's profile picture changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, profile-picture, identicon

Why has the [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) bot's profile pic changed from the beloved MSE logo to this:

[image]

A common Identicon?  Accident, or conspiracy?

Comment: Status-no-repro

Comment: This appears to have been fixed on MSE; however, it still looks wrong on most/all other sites. Site mods can fix it if they want, which may be what happened with MSE; I can't tell obviously.

Comment: I can't save it network-wide - the option is missing, so while I did fix it on MSE, the issue is persisting everywhere else.

Comment: @Catija It's back here and on SO, but still there on the others.

Comment: @Catija something is going on then: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409143/my-avatar-icon-has-reset-but-only-on-stack-overflow not only for the community user

Comment: I'm working on restoring it network-wide - we ran a backfill that did something... unexpected

Comment: Since it’s being changed, we might as well make it an unicorn now...

Comment: @EkadhSingh Not a bad idea, all things considered... or a stack of waffles.

Comment: Still broken on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)

Comment: @RobertColumbia broken everywhere but on MSE and SO.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Way back in the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194094/267572) we started salting Gravatar image URLs, but only for new users. Older users do *not* have a salted Gravatar URL.

Today we performed a backfill so we can drop an old column `Users.Email` which contains an email address only used for this purpose but we didn't take into account that users created prior to August 2013 would not have salted URLs. Community is one of those users.

It's gonna take a little while to unwind the backfill and fix
everything correctly!

**UPDATE 1** A fix has been approved but I'm not particularly keen on running another backfill network-wide on a Friday afternoon. It'll be run to address the issue with all affected users profile images on Monday morning (UTC).

**UPDATE 2** I'm running the backfill here on meta now, after verifying the backfill was successful it'll be on a couple of other smaller sites.

**UPDATE 3** Backfill was successful on meta, running on a smaller site now - assuming success, rest of the network is next.

**UPDATE 4** Annnnnd we're done. Apologies for the inconvenience folks

Comment: So [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-original-email-address-is-retained-in-the-system-even-after-theyve-cha) is implemented?

Comment: Will it be implemented by the planned change?

Comment: Area51 is an… odd case. It’s a fork of SE from many moons ago - each change we make in SE has to be painstakingly backported - I don’t think it’s likely I’ll touch it today

Comment: Not asking specifically about Area 51, but about the sites. The Email field is altogether gone on them now? What about the two cases where it had some use (1. legacy users who'd set up different emails to have different Gravatars on different sites as the manual uploading system didn't exist, and 2. unregistered users since their email isn't verified yet)? Also, is it no longer the case that one's old email address is retained after changing it?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I gotcha - today we’ll fix the backfill (which stores a gravatar profile image URL rather than calc it using email), next we’re working out a plan for unregistered, _then_ that column gets dropped (but only on SE network). However, no changes planned for Area51 so there will still be a disconnect between SE and Area51. I’d need to check the behaviour of the old email address but I’m pretty sure it does get kept around

Comment: What email address will be used for Gravatar images after that column is dropped?

Comment: @RyanM Whatever is configured in your [email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current)

Comment: I registered after August 2013, but I've still lost my Gravatar on a number of sites. Not all though, and I can't see any pattern that would determine which.

Comment: @curiousdannii yup, after investigation the problem goes a little deeper than just the cut-off of August 2013. We have a more comprehensive fix approved, but it won't roll out until Monday

Comment: I registered before 2013 and my gravitar has chnaged on some of those including SO and not others like here.

Comment: Good call on not running this friday night, wpuld have given you an upvote for it, but alas you already have it.

Comment: So it's changing so we can't have per-site emails anymore? Or rather, when did that change happen? We have to have everything under our "primary"? Not sure how I feel about this. For some sites I don't necessarily want to have it associated that way, since I am using my primary personal email for Stack Overflow as I consider it part of my "professional" profile. But some others, I'd rather not...

Comment: @JeffMercado It’s been like this for…. 4 years? We don’t _use_ these per site email addresses except for Gravatar (and one other, rarely used, case) - they’ve been legacy since we launched account level [email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature)

Comment: @JeffMercado using two seperate profiles, both with their own login is still supported. Just make sure youndon't accidentally trigger a merger of them.

Comment: [Could this fix have caused this bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367595/inconsistent-identicon-between-main-and-meta-sites)

Comment: Searching here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identicon+profile-picture found blame?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193894/registering-on-a-new-site-uses-identicon-instead-of-gravatar - same date.

Comment: In So.ja, it has been fixed on the main site, but it remains the problem with the meta. / ref. https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, from the edit profile menu, it looks right (just clicked the "Change picture" button and did not change which one was selected):

[image]

Gravatar bug? [blame-caching](/questions/tagged/blame-caching)? ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah, there's a recent bug report on MSO about sudden gravatar changes...

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: How are you able to change Community's picture?

Comment: @GoodDeeds That's a thing moderators can do. Its intended usage is to rollback or wipe any offensive profiles or impersonation, and is occasionally used to change usernames bypassing the 30-day limit upon user request; here, I used it to reset my site's community profile on main.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino doubt it's done by moderators though. Community user avatar is network wide, so Community Team should be making the avatar change.