# Private section in the profile

Tags: support, profile-page

I have just noticed yesterday that there is a new "private" section appearing in my profile.

Is this a recent addition, because I have not seen it like that before? If I recall correctly, the email and real name fields were available before, but without being marked as private.

[image]

Comment: A-ha! So your real name *is* Laszlo Papp. Just as I suspected.

Comment: -1 circle isn't freehand

Comment: You are wearing an extremely cool hat. I suggest you take a snapshot and use that as your profile picture once the Winter Bash gets over sometime in January next year :)

Comment: Did you mean to post your email address publicly? because you did.

Comment: @Tim: yes, it was not accidental. It is available in many open source projects as well, and here it is even more difficult for spams to reuse since it is a screenshot, not text.

Comment: IMO it would also make sense to show this when editing the profile too.

Comment: @lpap doff the hat.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you're aware, the reason for this change in the display of your private fields has been [given in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1697661#1697661):

> It's always been there. We just moved it to the bottom and marked it "private" because folks kept thinking it was public.

The fields have always been available, yes, but they have always been considered private as well. Only you and a site's moderators can see those private fields in your profile; nobody else can.

Unless you upload a screenshot of your profile containing those fields, but you would never do that.

Comment: But "recent names" and "helpful flags" are also private...

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Actually, I was thinking the same thing just yesterday.

Comment: *Unless you upload a screenshot of your profile containing those fields, but you would never do that.* > Brilliant

Comment: @Duncan: Heh, [that didn't come from me though](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/213034/revisions) :)