# How can I hide my email from other members at stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, email

I went to preferences, but I didn't see any option to make my email private. I did a search on this site regarding this query, but I was not satisfied with the answer. It seems only moderators can view my email, but there should be an option to make my email public if in case it is private (I should be able to toggle between public and private). But there is no such option, so how do I make sure that my email is private?

Also I don't receive any email in my Gmail inbox if there are any unread messages at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your email **is** private. If you want it public you'd have to put it in the About Me section.

Comment: There is no option to make it public or private.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple things in one question. Start a new question regarding the missing email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Email and real name [are mostly private](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213032/private-section-in-the-profile), but if you want it to be public you can place it in the "about me" section on your profile and you're welcome to put something like "I do C# contract work, contact me at john.doe@example.com for a quote".

Otherwise only SE staff and moderators at the sites you're registered on [can see it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149636/who-can-see-what-in-my-profile/149637#149637). If it worries you they're going to send you spam (never happens BTW) you can always register using  a throwaway e-mail address.

I receive notifications / newsletters just fine to my Gmail account, but under your account preferences the minimum time for unread inbox messages is three hours. Maybe you are checking them more often on-site or don't have that set?